# How to listen to own triggered Socket Event

Tags: javascript, socket.io

For instance the client sends a document via socket and the other client listen in that event to get the new document. Client A sends the new doc to socket and pushes these into the local array.

```
// Client A
const documents =  []

sendDocument() {
      if (!this.document.trim()) return
      // Predefine Object
      const document = {
        author: this.authUser.username,
        date: new Date().toJSON(),
        text: this.document.trim()
      }
      // Post via Socket
      socket.emit(`send-document`, document)
      // Add Document into local Documents-Array
      documents.push(document);
},
```

Then Socket-Server broadcasts this document to Client B

```
// Socket Server
const docs = []

socket.on(`send-document`, async (data) => {
    // We use PouchDB as DB Solution
    try {
      db.post(data)
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    // Push new Document into Servers Docs-Array
    docs.push(data)
    // Broadcast new Document to other Clients
    socket.broadcast.emit(`new-document`, data)
})
```

So now Client B listen to that event and get the new Document send by Client A

```
// Client B
const documents = []

socket.on(`new-document`, (document) => {
      this.documents.push(document)
})
```

So far so good. works like a charm.

But now I want Client A to listen to the event Client A triggered like Client B does.

I dont want to let the Client pushes its own created document - I want it to listen to the event and then pushes the received document.

Why you may asks

Well, its because PouchDB creates an _id property on Socket-Server, which I need for all clients especially the creaters Client.

So my questions is, how to listen to the event the client triggers itself. For now only other clients listen, but the creaters client doesn't listen to itself.

I hope its clear, what I mean :)

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: `socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'hello friends!');` // sending to all clients except sender https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: if you want to send to ALL connected clients (including sender) then use `io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');`

Comment: @equaliser you can do what @GrafiCodeStudio recommended OR also just `socket.emit` the same event after `socket.broadcast`

Comment: uhh wow. yo got it. Thank you both! :D

Comment: @equaliser Great to hear you fixed your problem :). Feel free to add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so other people  having the same problem can easily find a solution